# arg[v] input and output values

Tags: c

```
int 
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    if (2 <= *argv[1] && *argv[1] <= 20){
         n = *argv[1];

    return 0;
}
```

So I'm trying to set the value of n = argv[1]. 
Input is `"C: myprogram 4"`  so the output should be 4. However when I printed the value of n I got back 52. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASCII code of `'4'` is not `4` but `52`. If you want actual numbers instead of strings use `atoi(argv[1])` to convert the first argument to a n integer.

Comment: Please note that `atoi()` by definition produces Undefined Behavior on any error condition. For string-to-number conversion that allows for the possibility of handling errors, use `strtol()` (or `strtoul()` if appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

Notice the type of `argv[i]`:

```
main(int argc, char* argv[])
                 ^
                 | argv[i] is a string.
```

If you index and access elements of `*argv[i]` it is basically a **char not int**. That is the reason that `'4'` is interpreted as `52` that is the ASCII value of char `'4'`.

To treat and `argv[i]` value as integer convert it into int. Better convert using [`int atoi (const char * str);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

```
int n = atoi(argv[i]);
```

**Note**:  following all are different:

```
   4   is a int
   '4'  is a char
   "4" is a string (\0 terminated)
```

Additionally, its good to check number of arguments passed to main using `argc` -- argument counter.

```
 if(argc < NoOfArgumentsNeeded) {
     // print error and exit
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass something by command line arguments they are character streams by default and are assigned to `**argv`. When you fetch `argv[i][j]` you get a single character.

And if you do `argv[i]` you get a string that is `"4"` in your case. So, what you are trying is wrong.

There reason you got `52` is ascii value of character `4` is `52`
 Using built in `atoi(str)` you can convert strings such as `"438"` to integer `438`
 Refer this code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int 
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n=-1;  //initialized to prevent garbage incase if case fails
    if (2 <= atoi(argv[1]) && atoi(argv[1]) <= 20){
         n = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    printf("%d",n);  
    return 0;
}
```